# Is there any way to create an app for python3 script?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

Py2app will create the app for python2. But for python3?
Has anyone succeeded in creating an app for python3 script?

Any clue would be helpful for my script in creating that.

Answer (score 1):

[`cx_freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

> Unlike these two tools, cx_Freeze is
>   cross platform and should work on any
>   platform that Python itself works on.
>   It requires Python 2.3 or higher since
>   it makes use of the zip import
>   facility which was introduced in that
>   version.

Comment: Does cx_freeze creates app for mac osx? I thought it creates only binary files

Comment: katrialex, could you please tell the exact option for cxfreeze which creates app? I tried to use it, but it just creates executable and libraries, without bundling them into single file.

Comment: I don't know, but the docs recommend InnoSetup: http://wiki.wxpython.org/InnoSetup

Comment: Ah. In that case I don't know. You could always self-extracting-zip up all the files that `cx_freeze` creates?

Answer (score 0):

[Py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/0.5.2) also create app for python3 script.

Comment: Experimental support only, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a blog entry about app builders a few days ago: http://publicfields.blogspot.com/2010/08/mac-os-application-builders-for-python.html

My personal opinion is the same as katriealex's: cx_freeze is the best solution at the moment. Although I did not manage to find a way of bundling binaries cx_freeze produces into a single app. I'd be happy to learn the way to do this and update the post accordingly )